# How can I count the number of adjectives in a text?

Tags: python

I have a set of [adjectives](https://gist.github.com/hugsy/8910dc78d208e40de42deb29e62df913). Now I want to count how many of these adjectives occur in texts.

This is the present code that I use:

```
from collections import Counter

adjectives = ["good", "bad", "worst"] #this will be replaced by the adjectives from the link

texts = ["This is not good", "The situation is bad, but not the worst", "How dare you, this is so good programmed! Very good!"]

for words in texts:
    counts = Counter(adjectives)
    
counts.items()
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong in my code please?

I tried to count the number of adjectives in a given list with a for loop. In the end, I expected the output:

```
dict_items([('good', 3), ('bad', 1), ('worst', 1)])
```

Comment: Your `words` variable is going to have the complete sentences.  You need to use `.split()` to chop it up into words.  Also, you are not counting your subject text -- you are counting the `adjectives`.  Don't worry about the adjectives until you have collected all the words.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the crude first attempt:

```
from collections import Counter

texts = ["This is not good", "The situation is bad, but not the worst", "How dare you, this is so good programmed! Very good!"]
counts = {}
for phrase in texts:
    counts.update(Counter(phrase.split()))
print( counts.items() )

adjectives = ["good", "bad", "worst"]
```

This collects ALL of the words, so you'll probably want something like:

```
for a in adjectives:
    print(a, counts[a])
```

However, as you try this, you'll see that this counts capitalized words separately from non-capitalized, and it includes punctuation.  You can do something like this:

```
for phrase in texts:
    phrase = phrase.lower().replace(',','').replace('!','')
    counts.update(Counter(phrase.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a new [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) of `adjectives` at each iteration while neglecting the `texts`.

Here is a possible *fix/solution* :

```
from string import punctuation

c = Counter()

for text in texts:
    c.update([
        adj for w in text.split()
        if (adj:=w.lower().strip(punctuation+" ")) in adjectives]
    )
```

Output :

```
print(c.items()) # dict_items([('good', 3), ('bad', 1), ('worst', 1)])
```